calling apply-templates from xpath
For brevity I often find I want to use XPath over XSLT, but I can't find an elegant way to do this expect to wrap any template match with a function like this:
<xsl:function name="mgx:iso" as="xs:string*">
    <xsl:param name="espTimeInstants" as="element(ESP_TIMEINSTANT)*"/>
    <xsl:param name="time" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="iso" select="$espTimeInstant">
       <xsl:with-param name="time" select="$time"/>
    </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:function>

<xsl:template mode="iso" match="ESP_TIMEINSTANT">
    <xsl:param name="time" as="xs:string"/>
    <xsl:sequence select="@date || 'T' || $time)"/>
</xsl:template>

so instead of having to explicitly call 'apply-templates' in the calling code, i can simply go:
<xsl:sequence select="string-join(mgx:iso($elements,'00:00:12'))"/>

Ideally I would be able to invoke the template directly maybe like this (I've made up the function 'apply-templates')
<xsl:sequence select="string-join(appy-templates('iso',$elements,('00:00:12')))"/>

instead of having to explicitly define a function adapter as defined above
I'm happy to write this function myself, but that requires me to do this
<xsl:function name="kooks:apply-templates">
   <xsl:param name="mode" as="xs:string"/>
   <xsl:param name="select" as="item()*"/>
   <xsl:param name="parameters" as="item()*"/>
   <xsl:apply-templates mode="$mode" select="$select">
      <xsl:with-param = ..eeeek.../>
   </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:function>

we can probably sidestep the parameter thing by always by convention having a 'params' parameter that takes a map, not nice, but its a workaround, but I cant dynamically invoke a template mode?
(I'm aware of various techniques to do this in XSLT 1.0, but they would be as much effort as my current workaround just more opaque, I'm pretty sure it still isnt possible to do this directly in XSLT 3.0)

I am not sure I fully understand your sample code but generally xsl:apply-templates is XSLT and it is not available in XPath and of course it all becomes more complicated to convert xsl:apply-templates into a function call if you use all features like xsl:with-param.

let me rewrite the question a bit

the question hopefully makes more sense now

The intent to string-join might be doable with <xsl:value-of separator=""><xsl:apply-templates select="$elements" mode="iso"><xsl:with-param name="time" select="'00:00:12'"/></xsl:apply-templates></xsl:value-of>. But that is an attempt for that particular example and it is XSLT, not XPath. Not sure there is a generic solution to replace xsl:apply-templates with a function, let's wait what Michael Kay or Dimitre Novatchev come up with.

I think really the underlying question is, can I dynamically define a mode in an apply templates, the rest I think is doable.
